# Injectivity in the Change of Variables Formula

Tags: integration

I badly need to apply the change of variables 
        \begin{array}{ll}
         u= t+s \\ 
         v= t^2+s^2;
        \end{array}

i.e.  $(u,v)= T(t,s)= (t+s,t^2+s^2)$,

to an integral;

however, the transformation $T$ I want to use is not injective...

Is there a way I can go around that problem?